# JSON - how to do common operations on request&response

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jackson

Example of the code #1:

```
@POST
@Path("/foo")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public SomeClassA foo(SomeOtherClassB input, @Context HttpServletResponse response, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {

    takeSomethingFromRequestAndPutOnResponseHeader(response, request);

    //... do more logic actions

    return x;
}

@POST
@Path("/bar")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public SomeClassC bar(SomeOtherClassD input, @Context HttpServletResponse response, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {

    takeSomethingFromRequestAndPutOnResponseHeader(response, request);

    //... do more logic actions

    return y;
}
```

As you can see we have lots of different API methods, and in each API we need to have request and response injected so that we will be able to do the **same** actions on them.

So, the question is: how can we make this code to be written only once?
* So, that we will not need to write on each method the lines of
*`@Context HttpServletResponse response, @Context HttpServletRequest request`*
* So, that we will not need to execute every time the method
*`takeSomethingFromRequestAndPutOnResponseHeader(response, request);`*

This is mainly in case someone forget to do this...
The reason is that we have the API running on several servers and we want to add the server url (from request) to the header in response, for easier debug of different environments.

Thanks a lot,
Uri.

What we would like to have is:

```
@POST
@Path("/foo")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public SomeClassA foo(SomeOtherClassB input) {
    //... do more logic actions
    return x;
}

@POST
@Path("/bar")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public SomeClassC bar(SomeOtherClassD input) {
    //... do more logic actions
    return y;
}
```

While this is written somewhere else **once**.

```
@Context HttpServletResponse response, @Context HttpServletRequest request
takeSomethingFromRequestAndPutOnResponseHeader(response, request);
```

Comment: What is the problem?? I don't exactly understand your requiremnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the HttpServletResponse and HttpServletRequest injected at the class level, by exposing and annotating HttpServletResponse/HttpServletRequest fields.  For example:

```
class MyResource {
@Context 
private HttpServletResponse response;
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;
.....
//API methods below.....

}
```

This way you don't need to explicitly pass the request and response as arguments to your API methods.

Comment: Yep :) created base class for all resources and injected response&request to all.<br/> One issue left unsolved - how to apply `takeSomethingFromRequestAndPutOnResponseHeader(response, request);` to all API calls - currently done with aspectj - but dont like it...

Comment: To address your second issue, you should take a look at what Friso suggested and try using a Filter.  You'd implement a Filter that does `takeSomethingFromRequestAndPutOnResponseHeader`.  A Filter's doFilter method gets passed a request and response... You can then map the Filter to your Resources in web.xml, and the filter will get invoked by the container when a request hits one of your API methods

Answer (score 1):

If you want this for all your API methods, why not use a http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html ?

This won't inject the request and response, but maybe you don't need them after takeSomethingFromRequestAndPutOnResponseHeader(response, request) has been called.

Comment: Thanks, also good idea, the issue is the Filter works on `ServletRequest` while first option injects `HttpServletRequest`. The difference is the the `HttpServletRequest` has method `getRequestURL()` that the `ServletRequest` does not have, while we need it.

Comment: You can easily cast the ServletRequest to HttpServletRequest, which it will in practice always be.

Comment: I thought I can... but something fails in casting... `HttpServletRequest
extends ServletRequest` and the instance I get is `ServletRequest`... so... not sure if this is good...

Comment: Weird, I've never seen that. What servlet container are you using (most likely a application server like Tomcat, jetty, JBoss, GlassFish, WebSphere ... ?)?